# Matrix with only positive entries whose inverse has only positive entries

Tags: matrices

I'm looking for a class of matrices such that if it contains a matrix with only positive entries then the inverse of said matrix also has only positive entries. I imagine an example of such a class would be the class of orthogonal matrices where the inverse is the transpose but i'm looking for a more general class if possible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix you are looking for what's called a "positive definite matrix"

Comment: If $A, B$ are "positive" in the sense that all entries are positive, then so does $AB$. This means $B$ cannot be an inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can find what you're looking for in ["When a Matrix and Its Inverse Are Nonnegative" by J. Ding and N. H. Rhee](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/missouri-journal-of-mathematical-sciences/volume-26/issue-1/When-a-Matrix-and-Its-Inverse-Are-Nonnegative/10.35834/mjms/1404997113.full), where theorem 5.1 states:

"A matrix and its inverse are nonnegative matrices if and
only if it is the product of a diagonal matrix with all positive diagonal entries
and a permutation matrix."